# Sign Up screen with Parse.com Android Studio

Tags: java, android, authentication, parse-platform

I'm an Android student and I'm trying to set up a Sign Up screen and save the user in parse.com but when I click on Sign Up button gives me error and I don't know why. Also I don't know how to test if the password and repeat password editable texts are the same.

```
public void onCreate (Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signupscreen);

        Button signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);

        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                String username = String.valueOf(findViewById(R.id.username_edittext));
                String password = String.valueOf(findViewById(R.id.password_edittext));
                String repassword = String.valueOf(findViewById(R.id.repassword_edittext));
                String email = String.valueOf(findViewById(R.id.email_edittext));
                String universitat = String.valueOf(findViewById(R.id.universitat_edittext));
                String carrera = String.valueOf(findViewById(R.id.carrera_edittext));


                // Force user to fill up the form
                if (username.equals("") && password.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please complete the sign up form",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    // Save new user data into Parse.com Data Storage
                    ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                    user.setUsername(username);
                    user.setPassword(password);
                    user.setEmail(email);
                    // Introduir universitat i carrera d'una llista de la DB sincronitzada amb Parse
                    //user.put("carrera", carrera);
                    //user.put("universitat", universitat);

                    Log.v("username: ", username);
                    Log.v("password: ", password);
                    Log.v("email: ", email);

                    user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                // Show a simple Toast message upon successful registration
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Successfully Signed up, please log in.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Sign up Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Error message:

```
06-09 22:23:52.764    5833-6759/com.example.aleix.selenotesapp D/libc﹕ [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 13(0x6170692e706172),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
06-09 22:23:52.764    5833-6759/com.example.aleix.selenotesapp D/libc﹕ [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, err=8
06-09 22:23:52.764    5833-6759/com.example.aleix.selenotesapp D/libc﹕ [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 13(0x6170692e706172),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 1024
06-09 22:23:52.764    5833-6759/com.example.aleix.selenotesapp D/libc﹕ [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, pass to proxy
06-09 22:23:52.774    5833-6759/com.example.aleix.selenotesapp D/libc﹕ [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy+
06-09 22:23:52.774    5833-6759/com.example.aleix.selenotesapp D/libc﹕ [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy get netid:0
06-09 22:23:52.814    5833-6759/com.example.aleix.selenotesapp D/libc﹕ [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy-, success
06-09 22:23:52.824    5833-6759/com.example.aleix.selenotesapp D/libc﹕ [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 13(0x35342e38382e31),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
06-09 22:23:52.824    5833-6759/com.example.aleix.selenotesapp D/libc﹕ [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
06-09 22:23:53.324    5833-6759/com.example.aleix.selenotesapp D/libc﹕ [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 13(0x6170692e706172),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
06-09 22:23:53.324    5833-6759/com.example.aleix.selenotesapp D/libc﹕ [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, err=8
```

Comment: By the way, `if (username.equals("") && password.equals("")) {` is probably not what you wanted. Checking if 2 passwords are the same is as simple as `if !(password.equals(repassword))`. Finally, usually `editText.getText()` is used to get a string value.

Comment: @bbill Should I check if passwords are the same with an else if?

Comment: Sure, that would make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned above, usually you would use something like

```
findViewById(R.id.username_edittext).getText().toString()
```

to get an `EditText`'s value.

Comment: Did you cast it? `((EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_edittext))`